# Anaglyph 3D rendering with JMonkeyEngine

Tags: java, 3d, jmonkeyengine

How to do an Anaglyph 3D rendering with JMonkeyEngine ?

I tested the StereoRenderPass class :

[http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/forum/index.php?topic=7168.30](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/forum/index.php?topic=7168.msg87278#msg87278)

but it generates errors when compiling.

**Update:**

I've finally succeed in integrating the Jme Context to my project.

But I don't know how to use it to produce an anaglyph and I haven't found any javadoc.

Can anyone help?

Comment: ... and what does the error say?

Comment: After having added some missing imports :
It is not able to find : "SceneImplementation" and GL11.